# calling stored procedure using entity framework database first approach

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, ef-database-first

I have been stuck on executing a stored procedure through asp.net mvc. I'm using Entity Framework version 5, database first approach. I want to execute a stored parameters whose parameters are passed through a front-end web page.

The stored procedure returns a table with all the columns. The table is StaggingInternal, so the sp returns:ù

```
select * from stagginginternal.
```

Using EF, in my asp.net mvc application, I used the edmx designer to get the sp, then in the model browser I selected the return type of the sp as entity. The name of the entity is stagginginternal.

But I get an exception everytime I try to execute the sp. The exception is :

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No mapping exists from object type
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[[<>f__AnonymousTyped`1[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], NewWeb, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] to a known managed provider
>   native type.

Code snippet:

```
var servername = from p in db2.AppClientServerDatabaseRelationships
              join q in db2.AppServers on p.ServerID equals q.ServerID
              where p.clientID == clientid
              select new {  q.ServerName };

var databasename = from p in db2.AppClientServerDatabaseRelationships
               join q in db2.AppDatabaseNames on p.DatabaseID equals q.DatabaseID
               where p.clientID == clientid
               select new { q.DatabaseName };

var datefrom = "01/01/2017";
var dateto = "01/01/2017";

var serverparameter = new SqlParameter("@serverName", servername);
var dbparameter = new SqlParameter("@awDatabase", databasename);
var dtTo = new SqlParameter("@dtTo", dateto);
var dtFrom = new SqlParameter("@dtFrom", datefrom);

List<Object> Parameters = new List<Object>();

Parameters.Add(serverparameter);
Parameters.Add(dbparameter);
Parameters.Add(dtTo);
Parameters.Add(dtFrom);

var result = db2.Database.SqlQuery<StaggingInternal>("exec App_aw_Internal @serverName,@awDatabase,@dtTo,@dtFrom",
  Parameters.ToArray()).ToList<StaggingInternal>();
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any ideas please?

Also, if something is unclear please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Are the result sets of linq queries typically reasonable values for Stored Proc parameters? Perhaps `servername[0]` and `databasename[0]` would make more sense

Comment: Possibly. I'm not sure, could you please tell me how I can access the first element of the linq result set. Actually that linq query will always return one result, i.e one server and one database. I tried servername[0] but I cannot apply indexing to an IQueryable. I might try servername.SingleOrDefault(). since it returns only one result

Comment: servername.SingleOrDefault() did not resolve the issue either.

Comment: both databasename and servername are queries you need to force evaluate the values with .Single()/.First()/.etc. To debug things I would just start with hardcoded strings.

Comment: it would be `servername.First().ServerName` and `databasename .First().DatabaseName`

Comment: @ConradFrix: Thanks a ton. It worked :). Just to understand why didn't servername.SingleOrDefault work? Isn't that supposed to return the result that the query gets?

Comment: The only reason `First` would work, but `Single` would fail is if there's more than one matching result, in which case, you would have gotten a different exception detailing that the sequence contains more than one matching item. Appending `OrDefault` makes no difference either way. The only time that matters is if there are no items returned *at all*, in which case, using `First` rather than `FirstOrDefault` will raise an exception. However, even with `FirstOrDefault`, you'll need to account for a null return value if there are no returned results.

Comment: @ChrisPratt : Thanks for the detailed explanation. I understood the difference between that, but my question was why first().DatabaseName ?

Comment: @newbie because `database.Name.First().GetType()` returns `<>f__AnonymousType01[System.String]` not `System.String` l

Comment: @ConradFrix: Ah, got it. Thank you :)